# Sum of Residues of $\psi^2(-z)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Compute the **Sum** of residues of $f(z) = \psi^2(-z)$, where $\psi(z)$ is the digamma function.

There are singularities for $z= 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, i.e. for all natural numbers.

But how do I compute the **sum** of the residues? It will be an infinite sum. but how should I do it?

Thanks. Also what **order are the singularities (poles)?**

I *believe it has something to do with Laurent series, but I am not sure...*

Comment: Any ideas to help here?

Answer (score 2):

The Laurent expansion around negative integers is 
$$\psi(-z) +\gamma=\frac{1}{z-n}+H_n +\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k} (H_n^{(k+1)}-\zeta(k+1))(z-n)^k $$

By squaring

$$\psi^2(-z) =\left(\frac{1}{z-n}+H_n-\gamma +\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k} (H_n^{(k+1)}-\zeta(k+1))(z-n)^k\right)^2 $$

Hence the residue is $2(H_n-\gamma)$.